# IDictionary interface without Remove()

Tags: c#, .net, collections, idictionary

Is there an IDictionary interface which does not support removal of Key-Value pairs?

Unfortunately, `IReadOnlyDictionary` does not help as it does not allow to modify the Key-Value pairs.

If not, what's a good way to implement one myself? Is this even a good idea?

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, you want to be able to _change_ entries in the dictionary, but not _remove_ entries?

Comment: What's the reason of doing this? Do you need a collection interface that will be part of a public API and does not support removing of objects?

Comment: @Chris/Ondrej: Yep. (note: null values are okay, but the keys must always be in the dictionary - due to various reasons)

Comment: @JohnnyMopp: this would leave the interface "dirty", I'd prefer a new interface. However, I hoped that there is something like that already in the BCL.

Comment: hey why dont you build your own class?? and just inherit it from Dictionary class and override the remove method.. i think it will work for you..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After the comments indicated that there is no built-in interface in .NET, it is probably best to create my own interface and implement it with an adapter to `Dictionary<TK,TV>`.

(if nothing better comes up, I'm going to accept my own answer in two days time)

Comment: We may need more information. Will you expose an interface or a class as part of your contract? In 2nd case explicit implementation and NotSupportedException may be viable. Moreover do not forget EditorBrowseableAtrribute too.

Comment: yupe as i commented.. I will suggest you to implement interface adapter to Dictionary and change the remove method .. thats it..